# What do I need to do to repair the plaster ceiling of my garage (on metal lath)?

Tags: ceiling, garage

Recently, I had some contractors come in and replace my garage lintel. Afterwards, I found that they'd had to break some of the white material that makes up the ceiling of the garage. It looks to me kind of like plaster on top of drywall with some sort of wire substrate.

[image: Image of my garage ceiling, with broken white material] (click to enlarge)

I'd like to just patch this up to make it look nicer, and to ensure there's not damage from general moisture, etc. Does this look like something I could just plaster over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the drywall you mention. It looks like conventional plaster, possibly in two layers.

You can certainly re-plaster right over that metal lath. It seems to be solid and flat yet. I'd watch some videos for technique and be sure you have a good quality, compatible product so it holds up over time.

Comment: Thank you. Despite having owned this house for a little over eight years, I'm still learning a lot about it. :) Haven't found any of those massive surprises that many people with Pittsburgh homes do (there was a recent thread at work of people finding blocked-off windows, sealed rooms, planter stones under their kitchen floor, etc), but I am still learning.